# Datapicker Mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, uwp

Como pegar o valor que esta no datepicker e fazer uma pesquisa no banco de dados? Tentei dessa forma mais não esta correto

```
var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT distinct id, Pedagio, Carro, Placa, Fabricante, Ano, Cor, Data FROM tcc WHERE Data = '" + txtDate.Date + "'", _connection);
```

Tava sem o nome que coloquei agora, mas continua sem realizar a ação.

```
<DatePicker x:Name="txtDate" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,208,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="415">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Busque o valor da propriedade [`Date`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/date-picker) neste controle.

```
var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT distinct id, Carro, Placa, Fabricante, Ano, Cor, Data   
FROM Novo WHERE Data = '"+ DatePicker.Date +"'", _connection);
```

Comment: Tentei e essa propriedade não funciona em app UWP.

Comment: O que ele exibe pra você? Se fosse xaml seria `.value`, mas, é sim `.date` em UWP.

Comment: ele me da a opção de DatePicker.DateProperty. Da erro se colocar so date.

Comment: @Jon Poste o XAML do seu controle DatePicker.

Comment: a xaml esta na postagem

Answer (score 2):

var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT distinct id, Carro, Placa, Fabricante, Ano, Cor, Data FROM Novo **WHERE** Data = '"+ DatePicker+"'", _connection);

ao invez de WHERE está WHARE, verifique se não é isso

Comment: Este é outro problema, mas, o que ele perguntou é sobre como obter a data do controle datepicker.

Comment: Ja identifiquei esse erro, mas não é por causa disso não.